# Should internet access be disabled on production servers?

Tags: untagged

We have Weblogic server and Database server on our production environment. 
Should we disable internet access on these servers to protect them from hacking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course !

The "regular" 3-tier architecture involves only **Front** servers (web-servers) are internet-connected, and are linked to applications servers through another network, prefferably firewalled.
[image: Intel's illustration]

Comment: Many thanks that is a very useful information for developers like me who have less exposure on production environments.

Comment: Sorry one more related question with regard to firewall in front of DB server. On firewall settings would we allow only the App server be able to access the DB through IP restrictions ? Or should there be any other tight security control for DB server ?

Comment: Ideally, only allow flow that you need. for example IP_application(all ports>1024) <=> IP_database(port 3306) for MySQL and so on. The App-DB firewall is a lot less important than the front-app firewall, as both applications and database are LAN-only. it epends on the security level you need.